# task.Wait(TimeSpan) not functioning as intended?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, task

I don't know if my error stems from bad understanding of the method or the implementation being incorrect. I am hoping you guys can help out.

```
private bool CheckIfFieldExists(string toSearch, string type) {
    bool doesFieldExist = false;
    if (type == "username") {
        Task t = playerDataDB.Child("Player").Child(toSearch).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                Debug.Log("Task was faulted: Pulling from database");
                return;
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                DataSnapshot snap = task.Result;
                if (snap.Exists) {
                    Debug.Log("field exists");
                    doesFieldExist = true;
                } else {
                    Debug.Log("field doesnt exist");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        t.Wait(ts);
        Debug.Log("returning field status");
        return doesFieldExist;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function is used to check if a field in my database exists. The goal is to use a task to pull the data as a DataSnapshot, iterate over that snapshot to see if the field exists, and return a Boolean depending on the result. My problem is, 'returning field status' debugs before 'field does/doesn't exist'. Why is this? I assume it's because tasks work asynchronously and it takes too long to finish, therefore the rest of the code executes before it's done. How can I make sure to wait until the task is done before continuing with any more code?

EDIT: (for those Googling for a solution)
Leave it to me to overcomplicate the solution, this worked for me:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckIfFieldExists(string toSearch, string type) {
    if (type == "username") {
        DataSnapshot snap = await playerDataDB.Child("Player").Child(toSearch).GetValueAsync();
        if (snap.Exists) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (type == "email") {
        DataSnapshot snap = await userAccountDB.Child("Users").Child(toSearch.Remove(toSearch.IndexOf("@"))).Child("email").GetValueAsync();
        if (snap.Exists) { 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Remember, if your intention is comparing the Task returned to another bool, you need to make the enclosing method async so that you can await the if-statement parameter. Without this, it will not compile, as Task != bool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it all totally wrong. You shouldn't be waiting for the task to ends. You should use the "power" of the async/await.

I strongly encourage you to read more about async/await especially about async/await all the way part.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

The code after the change would be:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckIfFieldExists(string toSearch, string type)
{
    if (type == "username")
    {
        var snap = await playerDataDB.Child("Player").Child(toSearch).GetValueAsync();
        return snap.Exists;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Although I don't understand why on code basis level you want to check whether some column exists (i suppose, that you control the schema of a DB)

But i don't know anything more about the use case so I don't say it is unnecessary.

And one more information about TimeSpan in Wait. It is only to point out, how long you want to wait the task. But as already mentioned, it is optional. Of course without it - you risk a deadlock situation. So it is good practise to enter some timeout after all (and handle it)

One important information regarding async/await. You use async/await for all IO or CPU bound operations. Everywhere, where there is something, that keeps you waiting (and it is not your code)

It is true, that it uses Tasks underneath (and a state machine) but using async/await normally should be easy and "without" tasks. To be honest, that was the whole point about creating them in the first place.

Comment: This looks like what I might need. I will try implementing this. Using the word 'column' is weird here, I am using Firebase by Google which uses a JSON structure for their database instead of a standard MYSQL db

Comment: Watch out only for two things. Doing everything async/await (even if not needed and even if it would be more appropriate to create tasks out of the jobs and run it multithread) That is the first temptation.

The second one is about doing async/await until some place in code. If you create async method --> you have to use await/async all the way UP. This is very importance. Otherwise, you will not benefit from it.

Good luck!

Comment: @Piotr this feels more like a workaround (which is a fine answer regegardless) although now i'm curious why the task (or better its continuationtask) cannot be waited on like op describes (which this question was about. Any ideas?

Comment: @sommmen - no, it is not workaround. It is the way you suppose to work with async/await. The state that the code was in the question was some kind of workaraound over posted anwser;)

The task can be waited. But there was a timeout of one seconds given. So if the query took more than 1 sec, then it skips the waiting and was going further with the code

Comment: @Piotr no - although i can see why you would think that. Op declared that he could not actually wait for the task to be completed see his comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61617576/4122889 I've also added a sample that demonstrates that it should (i think)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure to wait until the task is done before continuing with any more code?

This may sound a bit straight-forward but you can just remove the timeout:

```
       TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        t.Wait(ts);
```

to

```
t.Wait();
```

And you will indefinitely wait. Because this seems so straight-forward, i feel uncertain if this is wat you want to achieve.

Edit:

I whipped up a small sample which demonstrates the same and works under net47.
Perhaps unity handles async differently?

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start");
        Task contT = CallbackFunction().ContinueWith(task => {
            Console.WriteLine("First task completed");
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Returning continuation");
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
        contT.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("All done");
    }

    public async static Task<string> CallbackFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before Task.Delay");

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        Console.WriteLine("After Task.Delay - returning");

        return "Photograph";
    }

see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vKio38
```

EDIT2:

Even throwing op's code to dotnetfiddle shows that the sample should work:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/xa6lCv

output:

```
Before Task.Delay
After Task.Delay - returning
field exists
returning field status
True
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this earlier and it did not work. I retried it just for test sake and it did the same behavior as before.

Comment: As i responded. It have to work :) But you should not be using ContinueWith together with async. More info for example here: https://medium.com/@joni2nja/why-you-should-not-use-continuewith-in-your-async-code-c9eaf6087e64

Continuing writing code after await IS like "ContinueWith" part;)

Comment: @Piotr don't get me wrong here i recognize that op has miles to improve on the original answer but like i explain above - the code should work (perhaps for the wrong reasons) but i would not see why it should not work.

Comment: Yeah it should and it must. I suppose, that he didn't even checked (and wrote, he did check) nevertheless, when someone is claiming that he cannot bake a cookie in the drier, you will not instruct him how to set drier for high temperature, and then the cookie possibly maybe will cook. You will simply advise him to use the oven - wouldn't you agree?:) I suppose the answer was given, and we should not "argue" about the matter in the comment. I think the author is satisfied - so goal of this question was reached;)

Comment: I did check, I am assuming it didn't work due to me not providing the whole script, which means your missing about 150 lines of information. The accepted answer did work, and I edited the initial question to include my solution.